# Cannot set ID with this.id for input field

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Javascript and trying to remove the error message on key up event by calling a function removeError(), but I'm keep getting an Uncaught TypeError with the below code. I thought that 'this.id' should get me the p ID along with '_error', so that I could use the same function for the multiple fields because when I directly call 'fName_error' or 'lName_error' works fine.. Any advise would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

```js
function removeError() {
  document.getElementById(this.id + '_error').innerHTML = "";
}
```

```html
<input id="fName" type="text" name="firstName" onkeyup="removeError()" />
<span class="error"><p id="fName_error">Error</p></span>

<input id="lName" type="text" name="lastName" onkeyup="removeError()" />
<span class="error"><p id="lName_error">Error</p></span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this refers to window in this function.

You can pass the object to the function in the keyup handler.

```js
function removeError(inputEl) {
  document.getElementById(inputEl.id + '_error').innerHTML = "";
}
```

```html
<input id="fName" type="text" name="firstName" onkeyup="removeError(this)" />
<span class="error"><p id="fName_error">asdasd</p></span>
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

`this` points to the window object in your example. One option is to sent `this` as an argument to the function.

```js
function removeError(e) {
  document.getElementById(e.id+'_error').innerHTML = "";
}
```

```html
<input id="fName" type="text" name="firstName" onkeyup="removeError(this)" />
<span class="error"><p id="fName_error">Some Error</p></span>
Last Name

<input id="lName" type="text" name="lastName" onkeyup="removeError(this)" />
<span class="error"><p id="lName_error">Abnother Error</p></span>
```

Alternatively, you can add the event listener with `addEventListener()` which will pass an event to the function. Then the element will be in `e.target`:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('keyup', removeError)
})

function removeError(e) {
  document.getElementById(e.target.id+'_error').innerHTML = "";
}
```

```html
<input id="fName" type="text" name="firstName" />
<span class="error"><p id="fName_error">Some Error</p></span>
Last Name

<input id="lName" type="text" name="lastName" />
<span class="error"><p id="lName_error">Abnother Error</p></span>
```

Comment: When you use `addEventListener`, the context of `this` becomes the element itself.  So you could use `this.id` instead of `e.target.id`.

Comment: @RickHitchcock You have to be careful with that though, because it doesn't always -- if you use an arrow function as the callback `this` will still be the window.

Comment: True that for arrow functions.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the id as a param to the function.

```js
function removeError(id) {
  document.getElementById(id + '_error').innerHTML = "";
}
```

```html
<input id="fName" type="text" name="firstName" onkeyup="removeError('fName')" />
<span class="error"><p id="fName_error"></p></span>

<input id="lName" type="text" name="lastName" onkeyup="removeError('lName')" />
<span class="error"><p id="lName_error"></p></span>
```